# Clean way to query complex CosmosDB document

Tags: json, azure, nosql, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Background:

I wish to locate all the nested Features fields within my JSON document that have condition where "state" = "new" and where length(Features.id) > 4

```
      {
          "id": "123"
          "feedback" : {
             "Features" : [
                              {
                                "state":"new"
                                "id": "12345"

                              }
        

                          ]
     }
```

This is what I have tried to do:

Since this is a nested document. My query looks like this:

```
 SELECT
 c.feedback
 ARRAY(SELECT Features.state FROM c IN c.Features) AS Features FROM 
 c
 WHERE length(Features.id) >15
```

Or perhaps I must do:

```
   SELECT VALUE c.feedback.Features
   FROM c
   WHERE EXISTS(
   SELECT VALUE n
   FROM c IN c.Features
    WHERE f.state = "NotLinked” AND length(c.id) > 15
 )
```

However, the syntax is not correct and I am currently researching and looking for examples for this case

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.feedback FROM c join d in c.feedback.Features where d.state = "new" and length(d.id) > 4
```

You can refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-join).

Comment: This works thank you- Could I also do this in order to extract each nested id within the Features array???      SELECT  c.feedback.Features.id FROM c join d in c.feedback.Features where d.state = "new" and length(d.id) > 4

Comment: How can I extract the id that is embedded within this features array please? @stevezhao

Comment: try this:`SELECT d.id FROM c join d in c.feedback.Features where d.state = "new" and length(d.id) > 4`

Comment: Youve helped me tremendously! thank you so much. I was still a bit unsure even after reading the documentation. Thank you Zhao!!

Comment: You are welcome.You can use this sql and know what result like,`SELECT c,d FROM c join d in c.feedback.Features`.Then do some filter and select.

Comment: Wow you've helped me so much! Thank you I will continue to learn this!

Comment: Hi Steve Zhao, is there a way to write this, without using a JOIN? Select d.id FROM c join d in c.feedback.Features where d.state = "new" and length(d.id)>4?

Comment: why don't you want to use JOIN?

Comment: When I use in my LogicApp, it seems to be taking awhile. I am reading in the documentation that WHERE EXISTS is more efficient? I am still researching this

Comment: ok,you can also try this sql:`SELECT VALUE t.id FROM t IN f.feedback.Features where t.state = 'new' and length(t.id)>4`.

Comment: Steve Zhao, is there a way to do something like : SELECT d.* FROM c join d in c.feedback.Features where d.state = "LinkRequested" and length(d.id) > 15  to obtain all the documents, not just the id?

Comment: I notice that you have post a new question about this.The answer is right.If your Features array has more than one value,you can use this sql:`SELECT * FROM f where exists(SELECT VALUE t.id FROM t IN f.feedback.Features where t.state = 'new' and length(t.id)>4)`